# Why hadoop need ip hostname relation?

Tags: hadoop

Why hadoop system need config ip to hostname relation ?

I found some place call `getHostName` to get ip host relation: `FSNamesystem` `SecurityUtil` `NameNode`.

But I think without getHostName, It also works properly.

Is it used for kerberos security?

Comment: One ip can be assigned to multiple host names.

Comment: @zsxwing I still cannot understand why. One ip can be assigned to be multiple host names is useful in web server. Why hadoop need this function?

Comment: Hadoop needs to bind the connection to some host name. It's not safe to bind to all of the host names. So Hadoop needs to know which host name you want to use.

Comment: Thxs for your reply. Could u show me some hadoop service that bind special hostname.

Comment: How about this line:http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.0.0-cdh4.4.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataNode.java#555